# Java -- How do I call a method using args[]?

Tags: java, methods, readfile, writefile

Problem:
I don't know how to appropriately call the method like the assignment instructs me to.

Objective: 
Within the main method, call the `readFile` method with the first command line argument (`args[0]`), then call the `writeFile` method with the second command line argument (`args[1]`).

What I've tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if(args.length == 0)
    {
        inputFile = FileIO(args[0]);
    }
    if(args.length == 1)
    {
        outputFile = FileIO(args[1]);
    }
}
```

Code to work with:

```
public class FileIO {

    public void readFile(String inputFile)
    {

    }

    public void writeFile(String outputFile) 
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   -inputFile cannot be resolved to a variable
>   -The method FileIO(String) is undefined for the type FileIO

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do the assignment for you but I can give you hints that should let you get farther.

First related to the errors you're getting, you must declare the types of variables in `Java` so instead of just saying

`inputFile = FileIO(args[0])`

you must declare the type of that variable. I'm not sure what `FileIO()` returns but if it's a `File` object you would need to declare

`File inputFile = FileIO(args[0])`

Without that the compiler has no idea what `inputFile` is and throws that error.

Next it's telling you that `FileIO(String)` is not a function. FileIO is just a class but you forgot to specify which function in the class you want to use. I expect you meant to use `FileIO.readfile(args[0])` for example. It's not clear if your first `main` is an implementation of the `main` in `FileIO` or a separate file that just uses `FileIO` so I'd need to see more to go into more detail. Note that you must have an instance of a class (created using `new FileIO()` if you intend to call non-static methods in it.

Lastly, you need to understand the concept of zero-based arrays. An array with one element would have `array.length` tell you `1` but you would find the value at index `array[0]`. For example:

```
String[] args = ["a","b"];
args.length;  // This is 2
args[0];      // This is "a"
args[1];      // This is "b"
```

So the last element is always at index `array.length-1`.

When you say `if(args.length == 0)` you're really asking if the array is empty.

Comment: FileIO is the class defined in the second block of code in the post. They need help understanding methods as a whole, they don't understand how to call readFile() that is defined within FileIO class

Comment: yep - I noticed that just as I posted my first draft - edited now.